# Can I run springboot's with outer libraries?

Tags: spring-boot, jar

Now I've got two jars: `main-run.jar` and `my-starter.jar`.

`my-starter.jar` is a simple custom spring boot starter, which contains some `ApplicationRunner` in it.

`main-run.jar` is a whole application but without dependency of `my-starter`, so I want to add the dependency of `my-starter` when i run `main-run.jar`, here is my folder tree:

```
my-folder
  +-- main-run.jar
  +-- lib/
       +-- my-starter.jar
```

and I run `java -cp lib/my-starter.jar -jar main-run.jar`, and it just run the main application,  other `ApplicationRunner` in `my-starter.jar` doesn't run.

So, is there any way to make it work? I know I can rebuild and repackage the `main-run` with the dependency of `my-starter`, but I have no right to rebuild it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find a solution, just run this :

```
java \
  -cp <your main springboot jar> 
  -Dloader.path=<starter jar>
  org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

here's the link : https://mash213.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/hack-how-2-add-jars-2-springboot-classpath-with-jarlauncher/